# Sorting each row of a data frame

Tags: r, sorting

I am trying to sort each row of a data frame using this line,

```
sapply(df, function(x) sort(x))
```

However, the columns are getting sorted instead of the rows.

For example, this data frame

```
5          10          7          1          5
6           3          9          2          4
4           5          1          3          3
```

is ending up like this:

```
4           3          1          1          3
5           5          7          2          4
6          10          9          3          5
```

And I want this:

```
1 5 5 7 10
2 3 4 6 9
1 3 3 4 5
```

Any recommendations? Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use the plain `apply` function with `MARGIN = 1` to apply over rows and then transpose the result.

```
t(apply(df, 1, sort))
```

Comment: If MARGIN was 2, the output would have been the Matrix, but sorted by the columns. Why do we have to transpose it while sorting according to Rows?

Answer (score 5):

You can transpose it (coverts it to matrix), and split by column and sort

```
t(sapply(split(t(df), col(t(df))), sort))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# 1    1    5    5    7   10
# 2    2    3    4    6    9
# 3    1    3    3    4    5
```

Because a data.frame is a list of columns, when you `sapply` like that you are sorting the columns.

or `apply` by row

```
t(apply(df, 1, sort))
```

Comment: I had a similar idea: `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, seq_len(nrow(df))), sort))` I think any approach here involves converting each row to an atomic vector (so it can be sorted), which is roughly the same as converting the whole thing to matrix.

Comment: @Frank yea that works too, very slow for larger data though

Comment: Hm, maybe so -- that `t(sapply(` beats `do.call(rbind,lapply(` -- though it's not obvious to me why. For the other part, transposing before splitting looks wasteful and inferior to `split(df,seq_len(nrow(df)))`. If you have some benchmark in favor of transposing, I'd be surprised and interested.

Comment: @Frank yes, the first part is the slow part