# R - make a unique list of two columns interchangeably

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that I need to make it unique based on two columns interchangeably meaning:

**dataframe:**

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c("a",1,"bar","foo"),col2=c(1,"a","foo","bar"))
```

[image]

my goal is to keep only one instance of the two rows that contain the same data so, for example, keep `foo-bar` or `bar-foo` would suffice my need

an output can be:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base R way.

```
inx <- !duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort)))
df[inx, ]
```

One-liner:

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))), ]
#  col1 col2
#1    a    1
#3  bar  foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Sorting each row of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752475/sorting-each-row-of-a-data-frame) you can do

```
unique(t(apply(df, 1, sort)))
```

Comment: Convert that back to a data frame if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption your data is paired all the way through, a `for` loop can solve this for you.

```
## Establish the data.frame to write into
df2 <- df[1,]
## Loop through the remaining information
for( i in 2:nrow(df) ){
    df2 <- rbind(df2, 
                 if(df[i,"col2"] %in% df2[,"col1"] ){ next }else{ df[i,] } )
}
```

Comment: this will take so much time if the df is large, I have already found some solutions using `dplyr` and `data.table`, I was trying to find the easiest way